# How can I assign different buttons to load a different URL in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, iframe

I'm stuck on a problem with iFrames.

I have 6 buttons, which I want to open different URLs when pressed.

The Button HTML Code:

```
<div class="loadiframe">
    <button id="b1" data-src="http://Site1.com/">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div class="loadiframe">
    <button id="b2" data-src="http://Site2.com">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

and so on..

The iFrame HTML code:

```
<iframe id='frame' frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
```

and the Javascript:

```
function iframeChange() {
    var buttons = document.querySelector(".loadiframe"),
        iframe = document.getElementById('frame');

    buttons.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        iframe.src = e.target.dataset.src;
    });
}
window.onload = iframeChange;
```

My biggest problem would be the class="loadiframe" since the buttons are scattered across the page and I can't really put the buttons together and call it just 1 time.

Any suggestion as to a fix of this or a way around it?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the closing tag on the </iframe>, but the problem isn't that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an inline click event on the button:

```
<iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="http://site1.com"></iframe>

<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('frame').src='http://site2.com'">Button #1</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('frame').src='http://site3.com'">Button #2</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('frame').src='http://site4.com'">Button #3</button>
```

---

You could also use an `<a>` instead of `<button>`, then add `target="frame"` to your anchors:

```
<iframe name="frame" src="http://site1.com"></iframe>

<a href="http://site2.com" target="frame">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://site3.com" target="frame">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://site4.com" target="frame">Link 3</a>
```

No JavaScript needed.

Comment: Thanks over thought it more than I should of

Answer (score 1):

Please change this

```
var buttons = document.querySelector(".loadiframe"),
```

to this

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".loadiframe button"),
```

> querySelector : Returns the first element within the document (using
>   depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches
>   the specified group of selectors.
>
> querySelectorAll: Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors.

And, here is my jquery solution:

```
$('.loadiframe >button').click(function(){
    $('#frame').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
})
```

Comment: Nope still doesn't load. with var buttons = document.querySelector(".loadiframe"), it loaded the first button but with ALL added it doesnt load neither. I tried that before and im clueless x(

Comment: @KillahHerb did you try jquery

Comment: I wanted to avoid using jquery, but Thanks @zep_fan found me the way.